# Dynamic binding in c# where we cannot use Compiled data binding(x:bind)

Tags: c#, uwp, xbind

I am working on building a UWP application with c#, where in I found out about Compiled data binding(x:bind).
It has many advantageous like performance, compile time errors in xaml page, binding events etc.
When I go through one of the tutorial about compiled data binding, it clearly states we cannot use x:bind in scenarios, where we are binding objects dynamically. I am looking for an example, specifically for runtime binding which cannot be solved by using x:bind.
A small piece of code with dynamic object binding will be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Binding when I'm not sure if a specific property exists.
Example:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="Message">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" />
        // if binding fails, the value is set to 0
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress, FallbackValue=0}"
                     Maximum="1"
                     Background="Transparent" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
public class Message
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class MessageWithProgress : Message
{
    public double Progress { get; set; }
}
```

Still, you can avoid using Binding in this example by using [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/data-template-selector).